# Dynamically register button click event after init

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

I want to add an user control dynamically in the page. The user control must be added when i click a button:

```
protected void BtnAddCpe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CPEData cpeControl = Page.LoadControl("/Controls/Cpe/CPEData.ascx") as CPEData;

    cpeControl.ID = "Cpes_" + this.PhCPE.Controls.Count;
    cpeControl.ValidationGroup = "new_cpe_order";
    cpeControl.CPETypeList = this.SetCpeTypeList(this.CPETypeList);

    cpeControl.AggiungiCpeType += new CpeTypeEventHandler(Cpes_AggiungiCpeType);

    this.PhCPE.Controls.Add(cpeControl);
}
```

Obviously this line does not work

```
cpeControl.AggiungiCpeType += new CpeTypeEventHandler(Cpes_AggiungiCpeType);
```

because event must be registered during the Init event.

So which is the best ways to solve the problem?
Thanx